# Reprogramming a computer mouse's internal IC?

Tags: embedded, reverse-engineering

I have a mouse with an internal IC: [SPCP168A](http://datasheetcafe.databank.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/SPCP168A.pdf), having read about it, I discovered that it is specifically designed and programmed for the mouse functionality. 
I am interested in reprogramming the device to be able to use its "camera" (160frame/s).
My questions are:
Can I reprogram it, or is it an OTP?
Has anyone done something similar ?

Comment: i've seen articles detailing a hobby-based approach to hacking such devices, but they didn't mess around with the SoC...

Comment: The mouse sends uart or ps/2 data with information of its relative movement, it is easy to use that signal elsewhere.  What I won't to do is, get the frame to be able to process it with a different algorithm. (There is another sensor/IC that does that, ie: taking multiple frames per second, but I was hoping to repurpose this one, and it seems like an interesting challenge as well, (if it is possible of course))

Comment: Of interest, perhaps: http://hackaday.com/2017/07/29/injecting-code-into-mouse-firmware-should-be-your-next-hack/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Specifications for this particular chip (SPCP168A) don't show any explicit serial/SPI port. Also, there is no indication in blogosphere that this particular chip has any field firmware update options. So it is very likely that it runs from a mask ROM.

However, there are other optical mice on the market, they are based on the original patented Avago technology. The [main chip ADNS-2051](http://www.bidouille.org/files/hack/mousecam/ADNS2051.pdf) does have an interface to a MCU, both some serial, and "quadrature outputs". There are some [hack examples that use this chip as 16x16 video matrix](https://www.bidouille.org/hack/mousecam) using Arduino.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not even sure the MCU inside that IC has programmable memory at all –  maybe a few bytes to set a custome USB Device and Vendor ID, but that's probably it. (Rest would be ROM)

I'm fairly certain it's designed specifically in a way that calculates the relative motion directly from the camera observation with hardware; that's very easy to design into hardware (and harder to do sufficiently fast in MCU software).

So I'm afraid this isn't the IC you're looking for.

But don't fret, there's slightly more expensive mice that come with oversized MCUs to connect the sensor to USB and implement more complex functionality, and if I were to look for reprogrammability, then there. Also, there's already been folks that [demonstrated](https://www.defcon.org/html/defcon-25/dc-25-speakers.html#Williams) that they can run malicious software on a gamer mouse.

Answer (score 5):

To make the manufacturing cost as low as possible the specially designed chip may be a 100% state machine design in hardware. Even if there was an internal MCU with firmware it is a good possibility that it is stored in masked ROM.

Comment: Read the linked datasheet. It specifically says there is an MCU. (Yes I know the datasheet wasn't linked until Pipe edited)

Comment: @ThePhoton I'd still presume Michael is right that the firmware almost exclusively sits in ROM – really no use for flash in a single-purpose mass-produced least-cost SoC.

Answer (score 4):

I've done this before for a school robotics project. The goal was to use position information from the mouse to use as a position sensor for a robot.

This is what I found:

1) All the mice I used had ASICS (And I'll bet that all of them do)

2) The ASIC that did have info was a chinese mouse and had a datasheet (instead of trying to find a datasheet for one particular mouse, I searched different mice for a one that I could find a datasheet for)

3) The mouse that I did have a datasheet for had two problems

- The data coming back from the mouse was not an absolute postion, but a \$ \Delta x \Delta y \$ position, it was noisy and not useful for absolute position, but useful for velocity or acceleration.
- After some reverse engineering, The mouse could be polled to find the values of the camera. However this could only be done on ~1 second intervals. Not very useful.

Comment: "After some reverse engineering, The mouse could be polled to find the values of the camera. However this could only be done on ~1 second intervals. Not very useful." Can you share how you went from relative movement to camera values?

Comment: The mouse had a register to poll the pixels of the camera. But the datasheet had a description of those registers, where yours does not. It looks like your mouse controller does not have those registers listed in the datasheet provided. The way I did it was look at the registers in the datasheet and then looked at the drivers and accessed the different registers with a program written in C.

Comment: So, basically you had a way to interface with the circuit (SPI, I²C) ?

Comment: I can't remember if we used the existing hardware or if we had to use a converter. I think I found a mouse that had an FCI to spi converter already built into it.